# Perl Subroutine and if-else block only evaluates the else block

Tags: regex, perl, if-statement

i am new to perl and using regex. I have a subroutine that is suppose to show that we are looking for a pattern that has  one of more dots".". The next line is to use this subroutine to check if there are dots in some patterns. However I find that the if block in my if/else statement is not evaluated, it only evaluates the else block.

```perl
my $hostname1 = "hh.uu";
my $hostname2 = "yyhu";

sub isDotted {
    return 1 if @_  =~ /\./g; return 0;
    }

if (isDotted($hostname1) != isDotted($hostname2))
{ 

    print "Must be equal\n";
}
else {
print "Perfect good to go\n";
}
```

This code prints out "Perfect good to go" and the fact that $hostname2 does not have a dot "." in it means it should print out "must be equal" but it does not evaluate the if block.

*Update: Sorry I have made the changes, this code should compile

Comment: I'm no perl expert but that `if()` seems to be missing a closing bracket `}` so I am really interested to know how it hits the `else{}` block without compilation errors.

Comment: Can't stress enough: ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`

Answer (score 5):

Perl passes arguments to subroutines in a fixed-name array (`@_`). So you have to extract your argument from that array. By using the bare array name, you are probably in "scalar context" and perl evaluates arrays in scalar context to be their size, `1` in this case. And `1` is never going to match `/\./`. The way to refer to the first element of array `@_` is `$_[0]`. The `/g` flag is also superfluous. So try changing that line to this:

```
    return 1 if $_[0]  =~ /\./; return 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Lots wrong with this code.

1) It does not compile. Use `perl -c script_name` to check if it compiles correctly.

2) For anything more that a one line script add

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

to the top of the script.

3) Parameters are passed into a subroutine in @_ not $_

4) `= ~` is two separate operators you want the `=~` operator

5) `hostname1` and `hostname2` are not the same as `$hostname1` and `$hostname2`, you should be using the latter to pass the values into your subrouteen.